# Subscribing to Observable not triggering change detection

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular2-observables, angular2-changedetection

I am using 'angular2-virtual-scroll' to implement load on demand. The items used to be driven by observable's using the async pipe triggered by the parent component. Now i am trying to call my service from the child. The call is successful and i get my data, i need to use the subscribe event to apply other logic. The issue is change detected does not appear to be working when i update my arrays in the subscribe function. I have read other similar issues but i have had no luck finding a solution.

This is the main component where the service calls are used. The inital request is done from the onInit. And then when you scroll down fetchMore is called.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy  } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { User } from './../models/user';
import { Role } from './../../roles/models/role';
import { UsersService } from './../services/users.service';
import { ChangeEvent } from 'angular2-virtual-scroll';
import { promise } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { VirtualScrollComponent } from 'angular2-virtual-scroll';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users-list',
  template: `
    <div class="status">
        Showing <span class="">{{indices?.start + 1}}</span>
        - <span class="">{{indices?.end}}</span>
        of <span class="">{{users?.length}}</span>
        <span>({{scrollItems?.length}} nodes)</span>
    </div>
    <virtual-scroll [childHeight]="75" [items]="users" (update)="scrollItems = $event" (end)="fetchMore($event)">
        <div #container>
            <app-user-info *ngFor="let user of scrollItems" [roles]="roles" [user]="user">
              <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['/users/edit/', user.id]" class="btn btn-action btn-edit">Edit</a>
              </li>
            </app-user-info>
            <div *ngIf="loading" class="loader">Loading...</div>
        </div>
    </virtual-scroll>
  `
})
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  users: User[] = [];
  @Input() roles: Role[];
  currentPage: number;
  scrollItems: User[];
  indices: ChangeEvent;
  readonly bufferSize: number = 20;
  loading: boolean;
  userServiceSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reset();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      if(this.userServiceSub) {
          this.userServiceSub.unsubscribe();
      }
  }

  reset() {
    this.loading=true;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.userServiceSub = this.usersService.getUsers(this.currentPage).subscribe(users => {
        this.users = users;
    });
  }

  fetchMore(event: ChangeEvent) {
    if (event.end !== this.users.length) return;
    this.loading=true;
    this.currentPage += 1;
    this.userServiceSub = this.usersService.getUsers(this.currentPage).subscribe(users => {
        this.users = this.users.concat(users);
    });
  }
}
```

From what i have read this could be a context issue but i am not sure. Any suggestions would be great.

"EDIT"

Looking at the source code for the plugin component i can see where the change event is captured.

```
VirtualScrollComponent.prototype.ngOnChanges = function (changes) {
    this.previousStart = undefined;
    this.previousEnd = undefined;
    var items = changes.items || {};
    if (changes.items != undefined && items.previousValue == undefined || (items.previousValue != undefined && items.previousValue.length === 0)) {
        this.startupLoop = true;
    }
    this.refresh();
};
```

If i put a breakpoint in this event it fires on the initial load, so when we instantiate the array to []. It fires when i click on the page. But it does not fire when the array is update in the subscribe event. I have even put a button in that sets the array to empty, and that updates the view so the subscribe function must be breaking the change detection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you say the change detection does not appear to be working, I assume you are referring to this: `*ngFor="let user of scrollItems"`?

I have not used that particular component nor do I have any running code to work with ... but I'd start by taking a closer look at this:

```
<virtual-scroll [childHeight]="75" 
                [items]="currentBuffer" 
                (update)="scrollItems = $event" 
                (end)="fetchMore($event)">
```

Maybe change the `(update)` to call a method just to ensure it is emitting and that you are getting what you expect back from it.

EDIT:
Here is an example subscription that updates the primary bound property showing the data for my page:

```
movies: IMovie[];

getMovies(): void {
    this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe(
        (movies: IMovie[]) => {
            this.movies = movies;
            this.performFilter(null);
        },
        (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
}
```

The change detection works fine in this case. So there is most likely something else going on causing the issue you are seeing.

Note that your template *does* need to bind to the property for the change detection to work. In my example, I'm binding to the `movies` property. In your example, you'd need to bind to the `users` property.

Comment: Good idea, but yer the event is firing correctly. And what i mean by change detection is when i update the array in the subscribe functions i expect the view to then update accordingly. Currently it does not update unless i click on the page, which is why i figured change detection was not triggering (until i click on the page) but i might be wrong. I am still fairly new to angular.

Comment: Which array are you referring to? You may need to provide a plunker or stackblitz to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: the "users" array, i realised the array called "currentbuffer" was not needed so i have edited the code accordingly. I will set up a plunker so i can show the issue. But from the example of the plugin when you updated the array in this case the "users" array change detection should trigger the update function which then causes the view to update. But since i have the update wrapped in the subscribed function the change detection does not fire.

Comment: Just about all of my code sets the key data property in a subscription and the change detection works fine. So I assume that there is something else wrong.

Comment: Yer its definitely a strange issue. I have updated my question with the code the plugin uses to handle the array change. It does not get hit when i update my array in the subscribe function.

Comment: figured it out, well sort of. In order to get the change detection working i had to markForCheck. Im not sure why because like you said i have used subscribe to set values before and had no problems. Anyway thank you for your help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

So change detection was not firing. I had to use "ChangeDetectorRef" with the function "markForCheck" to get change detection to work correctly. I am not sure why so i definitely have some research to do.