# Angular 8 UI observable not triggering change detection - ChangeDetectionStrategy is set to default

Tags: angular, rxjs, signalr, angular8

I have a container component with a service injected into it. The service contains an observable. In the container component's template, I am binding that observable to a child component's input property using an async pipe. Everything seems to work except that I must interact with the UI to get change detection to fire and display the data that was pushed through the observable.

(by not updating I mean it seems that:  `<ng-container *ngFor="let section of sections;">` in the child component html is not executing)

I have tried many things including creating another observable in the parent component and relaying the data from the service through that observable - but this was just a troubleshooting measure and is very crufty. It had the same results I believe.

Note:

```
1. The service is pulling data from a .net backend via a socket (SignalR).
2. I am also using Angular Material's drag and drop library in this project.
3. **This post seems very similar**, but I can't discern a cause or solution from it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955143/subscribing-to-observable-not-triggering-change-detection
4. I mention 3 because that person was using angular material's infinite scrolling library and I am using drag and drop. Maybe something in that library is interfering with change detection.
5. There is no OnPush change detection anywhere in this project
```

Service:

```
export class DocumentCreationService {

  private library = new Subject<DocumentSection[]>();
  public library$ = this.library.asObservable();
...
  private registerOnServerEvents(): void {

  this.proxy.on('documentSectionsRetrieved', (result: DocumentSection[]) => {
        this.library.next(result);
    });
  }
...
  public retrieveDocumentSections = () => {
    this.proxy.invoke('getDocumentSections')
              .then(() => console.log("getDocumentSections completed"))
              .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
...
}
```

Container ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent {
...
  constructor(public documentCreator: DocumentCreationService) { }
}
```

Container html:

```
<document-section-library #library [hidden]="selectedView !== 'library'" [sections]="documentCreator.library$ | async" [connectedDropTargets]="dropTargets">
```

Child ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'document-section-library',
  templateUrl: './document-section-library.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./document-section-library.component.scss']
})
export class DocumentSectionLibraryComponent {
...
  @Input()
  public sections: DocumentSection[];
...
```

Child html:

```
  <div class="document-section-library__contentarea" cdkDropList id="sectionLibrary" #sectionLibrary="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="connectedDropTargets" [cdkDropListData]="sections" (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let section of sections;">

      <ng-template [ngIf]="section.content && section.content.length > 0" [ngIfElse]="table">

        <document-section-custom class="document-section" cdkDrag 
          [id]="section.id"
          [templateId]="section.templateId" 
          [name]="section.name" 
          [enabled]="section.enabled" 
          [content]="section.content">
        </document-section-custom>

      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #table>
        <document-section-table class="document-section" cdkDrag 
          [id]="section.id" 
          [templateId]="section.templateId"
          [name]="section.name" 
          [enabled]="section.enabled" 
          [content]="section.content">
        </document-section-table>
      </ng-template>

    </ng-container>

  </div>
```

I would like the UI to reflect the data pushed via the observable immediately, without my needing to click on something or otherwise interact with the UI.

In this case I am trying to do this with an observable because I couldn't seem to get it working any other way either.

Ultimately, what I would really like, is to just have an array of DocumentSection as a public property in the service, update that array via methods on the service, and have the change to the array reflected immediately. I am not sure I even really need an observable for that. I would love to have the property on the service act like a local property on the component.

So two questions:

1. What is going on with this change detection issue and how can I solve it?
2. Why can't (or can) I, just create a public array on the service and bind that normally (not via an async pipe) and have it work in the same way it would if it were a public property on the container component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately this seems to have been some kind of conflict/issue with Angular and JQuery and/or the signalr (pre .net core) library - that signalr library has a dependency on JQuery. I replaced the signalr library with a newer .NET Core version (and I updated the backend to .NET Core as well of course) and removed JQuery and everything worked properly. I wish I could have gotten a better root cause for anyone else hitting this, but after 48 hours fighting this, I'm happily moving on.

If anyone has any thoughts/ideas as to what about those two libraries may have been causing the issues, I am still interested.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what's happening is that they subscription (`async` in the container view) is happening after the initial documents have arrived, so Angular doesn't pick up that emission?

I would try changing:

```
private library = new Subject<DocumentSection[]>();
```

to

```
private library = new BehaviorSubject<DocumentSection[]>([]);
```

Alternatively, you could try doing without observables altogether, and binding to a basic array accessed via a getter.

```
private _library = []; //  update when data is fetched
public get library() { return this._library || []; } // data-bind this
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just tried both suggestions - they both behave in the same was as the original. I'm starting to think that Angular Material's DnD library might be interfering with normal change detection.

Comment: I also changed the child component's array to a setter and added code to log when it executes. That code does not run until I click on the UI after the data retrieval. (the same UI interaction that triggers the UI rendering) Is that normal? That even if you push data to an observable, the component (TS) code won't execute until the next change detection cycle? I assumed the TS code ran independently of the HTML render - otherwise how would it know a data change occurred to fire the change detection.

Comment: It seems odd.  Are you sure that the data is pushed when you expect? For instance if you pipe the observable and print to the console, is anything printed?  Like `library$ = this.library.pipe(tap(docs => console.log(docs)));`

Comment: It definitely is/was. I did a lot of troubleshooting, ultimately it seems to be related to the signalr library that I was using. That library targets pre .NET Core backend (which as apporpriate for my use-case) and has a dependency on JQuery. I swapped out the backend with .NET Core 2.2, updated the Angular library to the .NET Core version, and removed JQuery -- after that everything worked as normal. No observables, just a regular array. @BettleJuice - thanks for your suggestions and assistance. I'm glad to know the universe/angular still functions as expected, this bug was giving me doubts.

Comment: Glad you found it.  It's the worst kind of bug to unearth.  One that had nothing to do with your code but comes from dependencies that you assume are safe to use.  Because it makes you doubt all the assumptions you've been making. like "does the browser really know that `1 < 2`?"

Comment: Exactly, I have been hitting angular pretty hard for over a year and I am still at the point where, when something goes wrong in that way, I'm not sure if it is a real bug or just some functionality I am misunderstanding.